# Is it possible to set MinWidth and MaxHeight of a Form?

Tags: vb6

I am new to using VB6 and I do it only because I have a project which created since 25 years ago.

I need to limit the size of a form, specifically MinWidth and MaxHeight.

I there any Property which can make me do that, like in WinForms or WPF?

example:

```
FormName.MinWidth =1000;
```

I tried this but not working correctly:

```
If W < 7399 Then
  W = 7400
  Enabled = False
  DoEvents: DoEvents
  Enabled = True
ElseIf W >= 7400 Then
  W = cmdSelect.Width
  DoEvents: DoEvents
  Enabled = True
End If
```

Comment: "WinForm" and "VB6" are very different technologies; which one are you using? Where is this code you wrote running? Where does `W` come from? What do you do with `W` once you set it here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general approach would be to respond to the `Form_Resize` event.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const MINWIDTH As Single = 1000
Private Const MAXHEIGHT As Single = 6000

Private Sub Form_Resize()
   If Me.WindowState = vbMinimized Then Exit Sub

   If Me.Width < MINWIDTH Then Me.Width = MINWIDTH
   If Me.Height > MAXHEIGHT Then Me.Height = MAXHEIGHT
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any chance of recursion here, when calling for a resize within the resize event?

Comment: Recursion doesn't seem to be a problem, but it's still necessary to protect the entire routine with an "On Error Resume Next" (or some other more elegant method).  This is because the routine will fail if the window is minimized.

Comment: @MarkMoulding Good catch, I updated my answer.  I, too, have never had trouble with recursion.

Comment: @RockJunior If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @RockJunior you haven't accepted the answer. Maybe you just voted it up? Click the check mark under the vote count.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Sure you were right i only Rate up but not accepted